# Why does NumPy only use 3 to 5 cores of my CPU?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, python-multithreading

I will of course have a look at Python multiprocessing with "pool" to solve that, but I'm wondering why is NumPy acting like that.

[image: Numpy behavior]

At best I can see:

- 1 core at 100%
- 2 cores around 70%
- 3 cores around 5%

With similar programs in Julia, there is much more parallelism happening.

Basically, my program is a collection of NumPy vector operations on very large arrays of image and 3D data. The only functions relying on other libraries are Ransac and reports exports with MatPlotLib.

```py
ransac_model, inliers = ransac(data, EllipseModel, min_samples, residual_threshold, max_trials=max_trials)
```

```py
plt.imshow(self.image)
fig = plt.gcf()
ax = fig.gca()
for x,y,c in zip(annotated_centers_x,annotated_centers_y,annotated_diameters):
    circle = plt.Circle((x,y),c,alpha = 0.2,color = 'blue')
    ax.add_patch(circle)
plt.savefig(path)
```

I'm not even sure that the other cores are used by NumpPy. Maybe it is actually these libraries.

I know that it is not the best strategy to run some big programs with NumPy. It would have been wiser to use Julia or TensorFlow/PyTorch tensors. But I have no choice here.

Could you explain me how NumPy behave in terms of parallelism?

I would also be interested if you know how to spot the parts of the code that takes too much time in Python. Something like the profiling library of Julia.

Thanks

Comment: You could have a look into [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) which does support a lot of NumPy functionality. It is a just in time compilation package for numerical computing using python. Specifically look into `prange` which provides relatively simple API for parallel operations of independent calculations.

Comment: Has your NumPy been compiled with MPI support? Generally, NumPy is compiled as single-threaded, and there will be no automated parallelism. Any multi-core effects you see are because the OS / CPU is dividing the labour between cores, not NumPy.

Comment: Related to your last paragraph: you have searched for "python profiling"?

Comment: Hi, yes I'm currently having a look at the various solutions for profiling in Python. Thanks for pointing MPI support, I did not know that.

Comment: I'm also looking into Numba. All this stuff look like much more complicated than Julia. Somehow I feel that I may had gain some time rewriting the program...

Comment: @Xiiryo If your Numpy-based is not a secret and not too large then you may paste its code in your Question. And if it is possible I'll try to apply number compiler to it to check if it will improve speed. Usually the only thing needed from Numba is to just add `@numba.njit(parallel = True)` decorator before your Numpy function and after that your function becomes parallel and faster. Try adding this decorator right before function beginning.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is very kind. Actually it is both secret and very large. I will have a look myself. I guess numba is worth to be learnt.